# "Going back" in a SLD tree in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have created a simple Prolog program and I'm trying to figure our what is the derivation / SLD tree.

```
a(X) :- b(X), c(X).
b(Y) :- d(Y), e(Y).
c(1).
d(1).
e(1).
```

Below is my failed try.

[image]

This representation does not make too much sense for me, because I don't know how to represent the transition between goal e(1) matched successfully by clause e(1) and goal c(x) from the first clause of the program, that now needs to be matched against a head.

The edge label should be clause that produces the derivation between goals right?

**[Later Edit] added a new SLD-"tree" variant that makes more sense to me...**

[image]

Comment: Use Google image search for [sld tree](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1745&bih=881&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=SXRBXby0De-kggf8grTgCQ&q=sld+tree&oq=sld+tree&gs_l=img.3..0i24l2.11107.11616..12234...0.0..0.67.125.2......0....1..gws-wiz-img.OJxTOx5vlhU&ved=0ahUKEwj8_IiFgN_jAhVvkuAKHXwBDZwQ4dUDCAY&uact=5) which will give you many images with sld trees. Clicking on the images can take you to the site where the image is hosted, and some sites will explain the sld image. This should help.

Comment: Of interest: [sldnfdraw](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/list?p=sldnfdraw). Tried to use this once but was more work than I expected because it requires several other apps to be manually installed. Might be of help.

Comment: Thank you @GuyCoder done and still doing it! :) I mostly see example with only one clause with two atoms... I'm not trying to get somebody to do my homework, I'm just studding on my own stuff... sometimes everything seems so simple and then... bam! total confusion!

Comment: Thank you! No problem. Any help is good. I wasn't ironic!

Comment: Also, when a question specific to SLD comes it is usually with a teacher that has one foot in Logic programming and other foot somewhere else, like math, the early days of Prolog, logic, or something else. If you are querying with keyword `Prolog`, try removing the keyword `Prolog` and it should expand the results. Will be a bit more looking, but will get you into how SLD is really used.